# iOS : Localizing MKMapView wordings

Tags: mkmapview, ios5

While using MKMapView is used to identify user's location , the location is pinned with Annotation "Current Location".

Can I use change the wordings of "Current Location"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change title and subtitle of current location annotation by setting

```
mapView.userLocation.subtitle = @"mySubt";
mapView.userLocation.title = @"title";
```